# How do I simulate a Tab key press when Return is pressed in a WPF application?

Tags: c#, wpf, keypress

In a WPF application, i have a window that has a lot of fields.
When the user uses the TAB key after filling each field, windows understands that it moves on to the next. This is pretty know behavior.

Now what I want to to, is make it simulate the TAB key, when in fact the RETURN gets hit.
So in my WPF xaml I added imply `KeyDown="userPressEnter"`

And in the code behind it:

```
private void userPressEnter(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.Key == Key.Return)
  {
    e.Key = Key.Tab // THIS IS NOT WORKING
  }
}
```

Now, obviously this is not working. But what I don't know is, how DO I make this work?

---

***EDIT 1 ==> FOUND A SOLUTION***

I found something that helped me out =)

```
private void userPressEnter(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
 if (e.Key == Key.Return)
 {
   TraversalRequest request = new TraversalRequest(FocusNavigationDirection.Next);
   MoveFocus(request);
 }
}
```

This way the Focus moves on the the next it can find :)

Comment: By simulate tab do you mean to move the cursor to the next field in the window?

Comment: Yea, move it to the next handler, so that can be a field or an button. So simulate the same behavior as if the user whould have hit TAB. That's why i simply try to give the system the TAB input, when in fact RETURN is pressed.

Comment: Problem of your solution: You need to add it to every single control, otherwise MoveFocus will not select the correct next field.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can look at a post here:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wpf/thread/c85892ca-08e3-40ca-ae9f-23396df6f3bd

Here's an example:

```
private void textBox1_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
            {
                TraversalRequest request = new TraversalRequest(FocusNavigationDirection.Next);
                request.Wrapped = true;
                ((TextBox)sender).MoveFocus(request);
            }
        }
```

Comment: hehe i just found that one too :) although i had to make it a bit different to get it to work ;)

Answer (score 4):

```
    protected override bool ProcessDialogKey(Keys keyData)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(keyData.ToString());

        switch (keyData)
        {
            case Keys.Enter:
                SendKeys.Send("{TAB}");
                break;
        }
        base.ProcessDialogKey(keyData);
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: This is a winforms solution. SendKeys is in the System.Windows.Forms dll and not in the System.Windows dll

Answer (score 4):

**How about make SendKeys Class Working like Winforms.SendKeys**

> https://michlg.wordpress.com/2013/02/05/wpf-send-keys/

```
public static class SendKeys
{
    public static void Send(Key key)
    {
        if (Keyboard.PrimaryDevice != null) {
            if (Keyboard.PrimaryDevice.ActiveSource != null) {
                var e1 = new KeyEventArgs(Keyboard.PrimaryDevice, Keyboard.PrimaryDevice.ActiveSource, 0, key) { RoutedEvent = Keyboard.KeyDownEvent };
                InputManager.Current.ProcessInput(e1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, as none of the other answers actually trigger another tab press event.

Comment: Much better solution than answer - FocusNavigationDirection.Next won't get into next control  from editable ComboBox.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should use that to simulate TAB :

```
SendKeys.Send("{TAB}");
```

Instead of

```
e.Key = Key.Tab
```

Sources : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.send.aspx

Comment: I know this method works for winforms apps, but does it also work for WPF?

Comment: You're right it doesn't... I've found this instead but i'm sure there is a better solution http://inputsimulator.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 1):

SendKeys.Send or SendKeys.SendWait will not work in a WPF application, so to answer the original question

```
if (e.Key == Key.Return)
{    
    KeyEventArgs tabPressEventArgs = new KeyEventArgs(Keyboard.PrimaryDevice, Keyboard.PrimaryDevice.ActiveSource, 0, Key.Tab) { RoutedEvent = Keyboard.KeyDownEvent };
    InputManager.Current.ProcessInput(tabPressEventArgs); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Method SelectNextControl of your Form

Comment: this is a WinForms Solution

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution is:

```
var ue = e.OriginalSource as FrameworkElement;

if (e.Key == Key.Return)
{
    e.Handled = true;
    ue.MoveFocus(new TraversalRequest(FocusNavigationDirection.Next));
}
```