# WPF and MVVM : How to move focus to the next Control automatically

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a little WPF Window with 2 TextBoxes Having Ordered TabIndex 0,1 and i want to move focus automatically from the first TextBox to the second  when i press Enter Key.
I Use MVVM Light.

Remark : This post is not duplicated. here I do not use Classic approach with event Handler but MVVM Pattern and as you know Code Behind is not allowed in view.

I Found a solution but I don't know if it respect MVVM Principle.
Here the code :

The View

```
<Window x:Class="WpfMMVLight2.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
    xmlns:cmd ="http://www.galasoft.ch/mvvmlight"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
    DataContext="{Binding MainViewModel}">
    <Grid FocusManager.FocusedElement="{Binding ElementName=tb1}">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="70"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="Text 1" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="tb1" Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5">
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="KeyDown">
                <cmd:EventToCommand PassEventArgsToCommand="True"
                Command ="{Binding KeyDownCommand, Mode=OneWay}"/>
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    </TextBox>


     <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Text="Text 2" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
     <TextBox x:Name="tb2" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5">
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="KeyDown">
                <cmd:EventToCommand PassEventArgsToCommand="True"
            Command ="{Binding KeyDownCommand, Mode=OneWay}"/>
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    </TextBox>

</Grid>
```

The ViewModel :

```
private ICommand _keydownCommand;

public ICommand KeyDownCommand
{
    get
    {
        if (_keydownCommand == null)
            _keydownCommand = new DelegateCommand<KeyEventArgs>(KeyDownCommandExecute);
        return _keydownCommand;
    }
}

private void KeyDownCommandExecute(KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e != null && e.Key == Key.Enter)
    {
        TraversalRequest request = new TraversalRequest(FocusNavigationDirection.Next);
        request.Wrapped = true;
        ((Control)e.Source).MoveFocus(request);
    }
}
```

I don't know if the use of `Control` class in ViewModel is allowed or not.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As you are using MVVM, you can use a Behavior for this:

```
public class TabOnEnterBehavior : Behavior<TextBox>
{

  protected override void OnAttached()
  {
    AssociatedObject.PreviewKeyDown += AssociatedObject_PreviewKeyDown;
  }

  private void AssociatedObject_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
  {
    if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
    {
      var request = new TraversalRequest(FocusNavigationDirection.Next);
      request.Wrapped = true;
      AssociatedObject.MoveFocus(request);
    }
  }

  protected override void OnDetaching()
  {
    AssociatedObject.PreviewKeyDown -= AssociatedObject_PreviewKeyDown;
  }

}
```

In your xaml:

```
<TextBox>
  <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
    <wpfTest:TabOnEnterBehavior />
  </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
</TextBox>
```

Comment: Thanks for good solution. I have very textbox on project, can i set this for default TextBox and don't add behaviors for all textbox?

Comment: @ar.gorgin: take a look a this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1647815/how-to-add-a-blend-behavior-in-a-style-setter

Comment: Very nice. Now I need a way to make right and left work but only when at the end or beginning of the text.

Comment: I am using a keydown icommand to add a new item to the list.  Once I do that I want the new item to be the active (selected) item.  I think I can just pass the keyeventargs to my delegate command, but is there a way to first execute my icommand, and then have the behavior trigger if I used this approach?

Answer (score 4):

Add a `PreviewKeyDown` event to your `TextBox` first:

```
<TextBox PreviewKeyDown="OnTextBoxKeyDown" />
```

Then create a `TraversalRequest` to move focus to the next item:

```
private void OnTextBoxKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.Return)
    {
        TraversalRequest request = new TraversalRequest(FocusNavigationDirection.Next);
        MoveFocus(request);
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

Alternatively, if you prefer using a Command, you can just set a `KeyBinding` in your `TextBox` :

```
<TextBox.InputBindings>
    <KeyBinding Key="Enter" Command="{Binding YourCommand}" />
</TextBox.InputBindings>
```

And just put pretty much the same thing as above in your `ICommand.Execute()` logic.

Also, same question here: [How do I simulate a Tab key press when Return is pressed in a WPF application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9025278/how-do-i-simulate-a-tab-key-press-when-return-is-pressed-in-a-wpf-application)

Comment: I follow MVVM pattern. I Think no events allowed.

Comment: Actually i use MVVM Light that Offer EventToCommand to convert Keydown Event to Command. But my problem is how to move Focus to Next TextBox without using EventHandler.

Comment: Again, MVVM is about separating view from logic. It's not about extremist "no events allowed". You are trying here to move focus, which is a pure UI action, why would you put it anywhere but in the UI (may it be xaml or xaml.cs) ? Make sure to remember this first: MVVM is not about "no code-behind" or "no events", it's about "no business in UI logic". You are completely entitled to use events there :)

Comment: Please take a look at the solution above from @Julien Poulin with Attached Behavior. It is clean and it respects MVVM principle.