# Xamarin Forms: How to programmatically tab between controls

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have a form that contains multiple fields such as entry, text area, dropdown, etc.
I want to switch to the next control when the user presses the return key from the keyboard by programmatically executing the tab key.

I tried this reference:
[How do I simulate a Tab key press when Return is pressed in a WPF application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9025278/how-do-i-simulate-a-tab-key-press-when-return-is-pressed-in-a-wpf-application)

I could not find the `TraversalRequest` inside `System.Windows.Input` Namespace

Comment: Do you want to achieve the result like this GIF? https://imgur.com/a/m3qIczP If so, `Entry` have a attribute `ReturnType`, If you want to tranfer to the next just set the `<Entry ReturnType="Next"></Entry>` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/text/entry#customizing-the-return-key

Comment: Yes, it works but in my case, my next entry field is not in the same layout hierarchy, due to UI requirement I have to take another layout and place the entry in that field. If the entry fields are in same layout then it works.

Comment: `due to UI requirement I have to take another layout and place the entry in that field. ` Can you share some related code or GIF about your issue?